# Query String ?& empty parameter Web API

Tags: c#, .net, url, asp.net-web-api, model-binding

Having the following action:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetStuff(
    string like = null,
    [FromUri]string[] state = null,
    [FromUri]string[] mode = null,
    [FromUri]string[] label = null,
)
```

when I query it as `/api/stuff?state=A&state=B` the model binder instantiates `state` array with 2 string values and it's kind enough to instantiate empty `mode` and `label` arrays so I don't need to check for nulls. However, if I query it as `/api/stuff?&state=A&state=B` (note extra ampersand) `mode` and `label` arrays are no longer empty - they contain a single `null` elements both. Why?

In my understanding the query strings are equivalent. Is there any way to fix it without writing custom binder?

Answer (score 3):

The two query strings are *not equivalent*. Your second query has a second, *nameless*, parameter.

`/api/stuff?state=A&state=B` = query-string with 1 parameter, `state`.

`/api/stuff?&state=A&state=B` = query-string with 2 parameters, `state` and a `nameless` one.

`?&` translates to a *nameless* parameter name having a `null` value.

The Route parser correctly parses `state`. However it detects a second parameter and it doesn't know where to put it. It ends up putting it in both your other parameters.

The Route parser's logic is similar with this:
- I'm looking for `state` ... oh here is it, let's populate.
- I'm looking for `mode` ... nothing found but hey there's a nameless one, let's populate with it.
- I'm looking for `label` ... nothing found but hey there's a nameless one, let's populate with it.

PS: you can send a nameless query-string parameter like this:

```
http://www.myurl.com/?=value
```

Comment: use backticks for code, for word emphasis you can use *italics* or **bold** (Ive edited your answer)

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I will sure do so from now on.

Comment: OMG, this is a weirdest behavior one could expect. In case if, say, there is `&extra=1` parameter in the query string the binder still doesn't know where to put `1` (and it doesn't). In other words, if there are no matches there is no reason to put non-matching values anywhere.

Comment: In your example if wouldn't put the `1` somewhere else. The situation I have described above happens only with nameless parameters.